# dynamic change doesn't work on vuejs input

Tags: vue.js

i'm working on a vue file and have a form :

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Montant</span>
    <input type="number" class="form-control"  v-model="amount" v-bind:value="pattern['value']"]>
</div>
```

my tab pattern is loaded like that :

```
var request = $.ajax({
url: '{{ path ('home') }}promos/pattern/'+value,
})
request.success(function(data){
    if(data['pattern']==='yes'){
        this.pattern=data[0];
        alert(this.pattern['value']);
    }
})
```

and my instance :

```
var instance = new Vue({
el: "#General",
data: {
    [...]
    pattern: []
}
```

and the request is made evertyime i do 'action a'. I have the right alert with the value i want everytime i do 'action a' but the input stays at 0 and won't dynamically change.

Comment: `v-model="amount"` rewrites whatever value you specify to `amount` value. Your `v-model` usage is wrong. 1) Where is your `amount` set? 2) Use either `v-model` OR `:value`, not both.

Comment: @wostex it doesn't work even if i delete the v-model

Comment: I guess `pattern` is an object. You should use `this.set(obj, prop, value)` in order to make it reactive if properties are not defined in `data`: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set If it doesn't help - provide a workable fiddle with dummy fetching etc.

Comment: but my `alert(this.pattern['value'])` works great, so that mean pattern is correctly setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your code. Firstly, let's look at your ajax request:

```
request.success(function(data){
    if(data['pattern']==='yes'){
        this.pattern=data[0];
        alert(this.pattern['value']);
    }
})
```

What is the form of your `data` response? Because you are checking something with `data['pattern']`, and then you are trying to associate to `this.pattern` something that you call `data[0]`

Then, as stated in @thanksd answer, you are referencing a wrong `this` in your ajax callback, you need to create a `self` variable:

```
var self = this

var request = $.ajax({
    url: '{{ path ('home') }}promos/pattern/'+value,
})

request.success(function(data){
    if(data['pattern']==='yes'){
        self.pattern=data[0];
        alert(this.pattern['value']);
    }
})
```

Finally, you write:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control"  v-model="amount" v-bind:value="pattern['value']"]>
```

So there are a few mistakes here. Firstly, you have a `]` at the end of the line that has nothing to do here.

Secondly, you are using `v-bind:value`, this is not something that is going to be responsive. If you want this input to be responsive, you should use `v-model` and set the value of `amount` when you want to change the input value.

Hope this helps

Comment: Technically, `v-bind:value` would still be responsive to changes in the `pattern` property. You mean that changes to the input's value wouldn't update the `pattern` property.

Comment: mmm I don't know, when I test it on a fiddle, the `value` is not responsive: https://jsfiddle.net/8dvggzhc/ Except if you get rid of the `v-model`

Comment: Yeah, without `v-model` is what I mean. Since `v-model` is just shorthand for `v-bind:value="something" v-on:input="something = $event.target.value"`, it's overriding the additional `v-bind` is his example.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. The `this` in your `success` handler is not referencing the Vue instance. You need to set a reference outside the scope of the handler and use that instead.
2. You can't chain a `success` callback to jQuery's `ajax` method in the first place. It's defined as a property in the parameter object passed to the call. (Maybe you copied code over wrong?)
3. You need to get rid of `v-model="amount"` if you want the input's value to reflect the value bound by `v-bind:value="pattern"`

Your code should look like this:

```
let self = this; // set a reference to the Vue instance outside the callback scope

var request = $.ajax({
  url: '{{ path ('home') }}promos/pattern/'+value,
  success: function(data) { // success handler should go in the parameter object
    if (data['pattern']==='yes') {
      self.pattern=data[0];
      alert(this.pattern['value']);
    }
  }
})
```